# Find out when the car make a maneuver

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I need to find out if the car make a maneuver like 45 degrees.

I'm trying to use `position.heading` from GPS in order to avoid magnetometer/gyro/accelerometer because they seem tricky to use.

What is the best way to achieve this ?

For starters, I'm trying to use the position headings in order to find out if it rotates, but when I rotate the emulator I take something like 0.1 degrees difference.  I don't know why since I rotate nearly 45 degrees.

Here is my code:

```js
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

class Geo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _GeoState createState() => _GeoState();
}

class _GeoState extends State<Geo> {
  double? _previousHeading;
  double? _currentHeading;
  double? _latitude;
  double? _longitude;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getCurrentLocation();
  }

  Future<void> _getCurrentLocation() async {
    try {
      late LocationSettings locationSettings;

      locationSettings = AndroidSettings(
        accuracy: LocationAccuracy.bestForNavigation,
        forceLocationManager: true,
        intervalDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
      );

      Stream<Position> positionStream =
          Geolocator.getPositionStream(locationSettings: locationSettings);

      positionStream.listen((Position position) {
        setState(() {
          _latitude = position.latitude;
          _longitude = position.longitude;
          _currentHeading = position.heading;
        });

        print('Latitude: $_latitude, Longitude: $_longitude');
        print('Heading: $_currentHeading degrees');
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error: $e');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Location and Heading Checker'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            if (_latitude != null && _longitude != null)
              Text(
                'Latitude: $_latitude, Longitude: $_longitude',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
              ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            if (_currentHeading != null)
              Text(
                'Heading: ${_currentHeading!.toStringAsFixed(2)} degrees',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
              ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            Text(
              'Check the console for location and heading updates.',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answers in Kotlin are acceptable also.

Answer (score 0):

To get a bearing from the GPS system, the device needs to be moving along a path. Make sure you are moving the device and then make a 90 degree turn in the path followed.

I would also checkout the position.speed to filter out fixes where the GPS does not detect any movement.

Comment: Is there any way I can do it for a stationary car ? 

I need to find out if he parked or not

Comment: Obviously if a car is stationary neither gps or accelerometer can tell you anything except that the car is stationary.

Comment: You would need to hold a history of changes, and then detect 'parking' as moving fast, moving slow, turning hard, stopped, sequence maybe?

Comment: Can I not for example use the heading of the position to find out if he do a manoeuvre ? 

For example he turns 45 degrees then  again to -45 and if the speed is zero he parked etc .

Comment: Also, if using GPS, 1000ms period is probably the most frequent you should use.  100ms is too short. You have to think about what your definition of "parking" is, and then design an algorithm to detect it.

Comment: Yiep I’m considering to use history with some duration delays , but I don’t know if compass is more suitable or position heading , because heading seems not so accurate some times … can I somehow take the linear or x axis only of a compass ?

Comment: Yes you need to somehow hold a short history and then detect a set of conditions that trigger your parking condition.

Comment: Speed is pretty important too, if you are trying to detect parking, because presumably it drops to zero.

Comment: I think gps can work, but reduce the fix frequency to 5 seconds say, record speed and bearing every five seconds for the previous rolling minute say, and then detect parking.

Comment: Anyway. Please upvote my answer if it helped